# What actually happens when a controller is created in MVC6?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, architecture, asp.net-core-mvc

When I'm trying to make a MVC6 application, I got an idea of putting a `ViewModel` layer to my site. So I want to achieve it with a service like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddViewModels();
}
```

So I got a view with correspond Model, and the usage is like this:

```
public IActionResult Detail([FromService]ArticleDetailViewModel vm)
{
    return View(vm);
}
```

The `ArticleDetailViewModel` should be auto generated by a factory like other service items. But I think adding all of my ViewModels to the ServiceProvider isn't a good way.

Then comes the question: 
How can I achieve this?

I've known that controller is created by a `DefaultControllerFactory` per request. But I've got no idea about when the factory is registered to the service and how the request can invoke the creation method?

Or maybe I'm going on the wrong way?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Letting view models being built up by the DI container is a REALLY really bad idea. A View Model is a DTO and should contain no dependencies. You should keep this completely separated.

Comment: Well, in this particular situation, I want to separate my logics to different view models to prevent a large and not maintainable controller , this view model is not just a DTO like model for views. Is this idea correct? Or there maybe better practice?

Comment: It good to keep Controllers thin, but you should also keep data and behavior separated. A view model contains data, while Controllers and Services contain behavior.

Comment: OK, I got it. Maybe I should add some classes like managers to hold my business logic. But let's talk back, when is the factory registered to the service and how the request can invoke the creation method? Can you provide some clues about it? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Instead of creating *Manager or *Services classes for your business layer, try creating *Handlers instead, where each class implements exactly 1 use case, as described  [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Comment: @Steven Got it, I'll have a try with *Handlers. But I still want to know when is the factory registered to the service and how the request can invoke the creation method.